# 'Procedure or function 'StoredProc' expects parameter '@variableInQuestion', which was not supplied' on variable formatted with a substring

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following stored proc that is throwing the aforementioned exception when I call it in a winform. The purpose of this form is to generate a number of randomized codes, format them, and store them in a database:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[StoredProc] (
@unimporantParam1 int,
@unimporantParam2 varchar(14),
@variableInQuestion varchar(10) OUT
)
As
Begin

exec dbo.GenerateRandomString 1,1,0,null,10,@variableInQuestion OUT

INSERT INTO [dbo].[sproc_table]
           ([unimportant_column1]
           ,[column_in_question]
           ,[unimportant_column2]
           ,[unimportant_column3]
           ,[unimportant_comlumn4])
     SELECT @unimportantParam1
           ,(SELECT SUBSTRING(@variableInQuestion, 1, 3) + '-' 
                + SUBSTRING(@variableInQuestion, 4, 4) + '-' 
                + SUBSTRING(@variableInQuestion, 8, 3))
           ,GETDATE()
           ,0
           ,@unimportantVariable2

END
```

Being called by this C#:

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        var numberOfCodes = int.Parse(txtCodes.Text);

        for (i = 1; i <= numberOfCodes; i++)
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand("StoredProc", conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@unimportantParam1", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "param1"));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@unimportantParam2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 14, "param2"));

                command.Parameters[0].Value = txtUnimportant1.Text;
                command.Parameters[1].Value = txtUnimportant2.Text;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I test it in SQL Server, it does what its supposed to, but when I test through the C# code, I get the above error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with the substring formatting or if its something else causing the error. I appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: Can you show your C# code that calls this?

Comment: You haven't included any of the code that calls this sproc. Does the sproc run when you execute it through Enterprise Manager directly?

Comment: Does this even need to be a parameter to `StoredProc` anyway? As opposed to a variable declared within it?

Answer (score 2):

When you create the variableInQuestion in your winForm you have to set it as a parameter without seeing your c# code I am assuming you have not done this, to do this the code looks like the following:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
SqlCommand cmd = new sqlCommand();

param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@variableInQuestion", SqlDbType.VarChar);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

after when you execute your stored procedure it will store the returned value in the command
and you can access it using:

```
String someString = cmd.Parameters["@variableInQuestion"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Please mark this as answered if you use it as I am new to the site I need to get my Reputation up.  Thanks

Comment: I've edited my question to better reflect what I was trying to do. Sorry for the scatter brained initial answer, I'm scrambling today.

Comment: @Rex_C - And the edit just shows what this answer says. You aren't adding the `@variableInQuestion` parameter to the collection.

Comment: `.ReturnValue` for an output parameter? Shouldn't it be `.Output` or `.InputOutput`?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I don't actually want to return the variableInQuestion, so should I remove '@variableInQuestion varchar(10) OUT' from the parameters list in the stored proc?

Comment: Yes. Then add a `DECLARE @variableInQuestion varchar(10)` at the beginning of the body of the stored procedure. (After the `BEGIN`)